# writeToFile in a .app

Tags: macos, applescript

I am currently trying to write content inside an `Applescript.app`
 which is a resource file.

I can write to the `.scpt` file if I copy it in a different folder out of the `Applescript.app`

```
@autoreleasepool {

NSError *error;

NSString *str = @"hello";



BOOL ok = [str writeToFile:@"/Users/Arnaud/main.scpt" atomically:YES encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:nil];

if (!ok) {

    NSLog(@"Error writing file at %@\n%@",

          @"/Users/Arnaud/main.scpt",[error localizedFailureReason]);
```

But if I try to write directly to the `.scpt` file inside of the `Applescript.app` at this path `@"/Users/Arnaud/Applescript/Contents/Resources/Scripts/main.scpt"`, it returns `(null)`. I guess I don't have authorization to access it because it is inside an `.app`?

Is there a workaround?

Answer (score 0):

so I just figured it out.... almost ashamed by how dumb this is but, well Im a complete beginner.

The path to the `Applescript.app` needed to contain the extension, I have been fooled by the finder bottom path which dont show extensions.

so I am now able to write in the file  `@"/Users/Arnaud/Applescript.app/Contents/Resources/Scripts/main.scpt"`